# Borel premeasure, prop 1.15 Folland

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-explanation

> A function $\mu_0: \mathcal{A} \to [0, \infty]$ will be called a $\textbf{premeasure}$, if
>   $\mu_0(\emptyset)=0$ andif $\{A_j\}_1^{\infty}$ is a sequence of disjoint sets in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\bigcup_{1}^{\infty} A_j \in \mathcal{A}$, then $$\mu_0 \left(\bigcup_1^{\infty} A_j \right)= \sum_1^{\infty} \mu_0 (A_j)$$
>
> Sets of the form $(a,b]$, $(a, \infty)$ or $\emptyset$ , where $-\infty \le a < b < \infty$ are **$h$-intervals.**
>
> **Proposition 1.15 (pg33)** Let $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be increasing and right continuous. If $(a_j, b_j]$ are disjoint $h$-intervals, 
>   $$\mu_0 \Big(\bigcup_{j=1}^n (a_j, b_j] \Big) := \sum_{j=1}^n [F(b_j)-F(a_j)]$$ 
>   and let $\mu_0 ( \emptyset) = 0 $. Then $\mu_0$ is a premeasure on algebra $\mathcal{A}$.

What I don't understand is, is $\mu_0$ even defined for sets of form $(a,\infty)$, $(-\infty, b]$? Or do we define 
$$ \mu_0( ( a, \infty)) := \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu_0((a,n]) = \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty} F(n) - F(a) $$

Comment: Yes. We can use the definition as written if we extend $F$ to $\mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty, +\infty\}$ by setting $F(-\infty) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x)$ and $F(+\infty) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} F(x)$. These limits may be $-\infty$ or $+\infty$ respectively, but by monotonicity they exist.

Comment: Have a look at the last paragraph on the bottom of page 34, just before the end of the proof.  Folland indicates how you are meant to deal with such intervals.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but how are we sure $\mu_0( (-\infty, \infty)) = F(+\infty) - F(-\infty)$ exists?  Xander, but this is based on the assumption that we have already define $\mu_0$ on $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: Actually, do we take by convention $(+\infty) - (-\infty) = + \infty$ if $F(-\infty)=-\infty$?